# Extracting object in html span class by specifc tag python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a specific part of a html text via beautifulsoup.

Although I can already produce a result its not the way I intend it to be.

Here is a snippet from what i would like to capture:

```
<span class="dotted produktPreview" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="" data-content="0.34 $/100 g" data-original-title="Baseprice">0.87</span>
```

So I am Using BeautifulSoup and my code so far is this:

```
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "1234"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

produktPreview = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'produktPreview'})
print(produktPreview)
```

So I basically want to get one level "deeper" into the span classes but I dont get it done, the result is more or less the exact line I pasted in the beginning,

The expected output or what iam looking for is that i want to put 2 tags/data into a dataframe. The tags/data are:

```
0.34 $/100 g
0.87
```

Which i want to extract from the html text, i just dont know how to parse it for soup.findall to extract them for me

thank you all for your help,
rued

Comment: what's the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`produktPreview` gives you a list.So pick the fist element and access by attribute.

```
print(produktPreview[0]["data-content"])
print(produktPreview[0].text)
```

If you have many `span` tag use for loop

```
for item in produktPreview:
    print(item["data-content"])
    print(item.text)
```